# Japanese sentence as question title

Tags: discussion

I recently had an [old post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32540/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A0%E3%81%9E) edited to replace a generic title with the Japanese sentence in question. I have no problem with the edit but I'm intrigued as to the motivation. I normally strive to make a question title which is meaningful to the problem and helpful as a search aid. In this case I failed to think of anything useful I could write and went with the generic and useless 'help understanding this sentence'.

In what ways does repeating the Japanese sentence as a title improves things for other users?

I guess I can think of one way, which is as a patch to the recent un-improvement of a users [summary page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7944/user3856370?tab=questions) where the questions are listed with the title only, and no context (it was much better the old way where you got to see the first few lines of the question, as you still see when doing a search).

Are there other reasons I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question titles also appear in the "Linked questions" and "Related questions" of a question and having some sort of keyword that tells something about the question makes a title more useful than a generic title. I think I have also clicked on "Help with this sentence" a couple of times, but usually was left frustrated with a "Related" question that didn't turn out to be related at all. I think putting the sentence as title is quite a lot better than a generic title.

Although the search functionality with Japanese is still limited, a less generic title also helps one relocate a question easier (e.g. in search results or on a user profile page) if one didn't bookmark the question but wanted to revisit it.